# How can I make a bar chart based on conditional formatting of the input data?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

### [Context]

I have a spreadsheet for my spending so I can keep track of my budget each week. I've used conditional formatting and sometimes manual formatting to colour code each purchase by category. I was thinking it would be helpful to have a bar chart that shows me which category I'm spending the most in.

### [Question]

I know that you can filter by cell formatting, so is there a smart way to go about this? Can Sheets see that this cell is this colour and so belongs to this category? And then to output a total of the value of each category? Or something along those lines.

Currently the only way I can think of doing it is by filtering by colour fill and taking all the data out manually and summing it. This obviously will be time consuming as it means I will have to constantly update this data as well as inputting my purchases. So not ideal :)

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Google Sheets built-in formulas have no access to cell formatting such as fill colors. You may want to insert a column and use [drop-down lists](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103) to record categories instead of using fill colors for the same. That would let you use `query()` to aggregate data in reports.

Comment: would [this reference](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/percentage-progress-bar-in-google-sheets/) be at all helpful using percentage progress bars as an option to consider?

Comment: Add an example of the conditional formatting you use to color code to your question.  That will help us understand what you are doing and how best to adapt it.